# Sychronize text with audio file

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, audio

I have a poem text inserted in an HTML page. Each verse of the poem is inserted into a div with an id corresponding to the number of the verse.

My wish is as follows:

Each verse has a matching audio file and when the user clicks the play button, playback starts and the audio of the corresponding verse is played back also the background Color changes to show the current verse. Also, the current verse div must be scrolled on top of the window.

The javascript code below doesn't work as expected and it changes the color for all div and not playing the sound correctly.

```
function lecture() {
  var nbDivs = 28;
  for (i = 1; i <= nbDivs.length; i++) {

    location.href = '#'+i;
    var div = document.getElementById(i);
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    var audio = new Audio(i + '.mp3');
    audio.play();
  }
}
```

For the HTML code is verse are in separated div elements with the number of the verse as an id.

That's what I've got till now but that's not working.

Any idea to do it in javascript or in Angular2

Answer (score 0):

I would propose to have a time-verse mapping where you specify which line starts at which time. Afterwards you could simply look for the corresponding div element and move that to the top or hide all previous elements.